# Store and update jsonb value in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table such as:

```
ID | Details
1  | {"name": "my_name", "phone": "1234", "address": "my address"}
2  | {"name": "his_name", "phone": "4321", "address": "his address"}
```

In this, Details is a jsonb object. I want to add another field named 'tags' to jsonb which should have some particular keys. In this case, "name", "phone". The final state after execution of the query should be:

```
 ID | Details
 1  | {"tags": {"name": "my_name", "phone": "1234"},"name": "my_name", "phone": "1234", "address":"my address"}
 2  | {"tags": {"name": "his_name", "phone": "4321"},"name": "his_name", "phone": "4321", "address":"his address"}
```

I can think of the following steps to get this done:

- Loop over each row and extract the details["name"] and details["phone"] in variables.
- Add these variables to the jsonb.

I cant think of how the respective postgres query for this should be. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `jsonb_build_object`

```
update t set details 
               = jsonb_build_object ( 'tags',
            jsonb_build_object( 'name', details->>'name', 'phone',details->>'phone')
                  ) 
|| details
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=79ea94b271772cb1874d099415dbff79)

Answer (score 1):

Use the concatenate operator, of course!

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

```sql
update t1 set details = details || '{"tags": {"name": "my_name"}}' where id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the keys you are interested in, build a new json value and append that to the column:

```
update the_table
  set details = details || jsonb_build_object('tags', 
                               jsonb_build_object('name', details -> 'name', 
                                                  'phone', details -> 'phone'));
```